# Natural gas fireplace pilot line size? Pilot stays lit, no main gas unless jumped

Tags: gas, fireplace, pilot-light

Natural gas fireplace pilot line size? Pilot stays lit, no main gas unless jumped

I replaced the pilot light, thermocouple, thermopile and igniter. The unit I bought has a much smaller pilot line than the old one. The old one was 1/4" aluminum, this new one is 1/8" copper line. The fittings are the same. Is this a generally accepted size?

I installed it and the pilot light works, but is much smaller than before and the knob that should increase or decrease the size of the flame does nothing. I'm guessing the pilot is a bit starved for fuel.

I bought a house and it has this 90s gas fireplace in it. The pilot wouldn't stay lit so I replaced the unit. The new unit lights and stays lit, but the main gas won't turn on. I can jump the th/thph circuit and it'll turn on, but after 20-30 mins it'll shut off. I need to check it with a multimeter.

My guess is that the thermopile isn't getting hot enough because the flame is starved. I plan on running the fireplace and checking the pile with a multimeter, then pulling the thermopile and putting a multimeter on it then hitting it with a torch.

If you have any other ideas or suggestions, please let me know. The fireplace has no other connections: just an on/off/thermostat switch on the back. There's an old thermostat wire attached to the back but no power running to it. If I jump the fireplace in the 'on' mode it'll turn on for a bit then shut the main gas valve, if I jump it in the 'off' position it'll turn on while I'm holding it then immediately turn off once I remove the jumper.